# ViewPager Fragments depend on data from parent Activity's bound service

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, communication

I have an Activity host a ViewPager with 5 Fragments (using FragmentPagerAdapter). I have to make sure that my Fragments only fill their Views when data available from the parent Activity  and that data is only available after the bound Service from parent Activity call the onSeviceConnected method.

So, i put all the code of creating ViewPager, ActionBar tabs, FragmentPagerAdapter,... in the onServiceConnected method and everything work well when the Activity first start or when i destroy and start it again. But when the configuration changes (when i rotate the screen), i debug my program and see that after Activity calling onCreate, the current selected Fragment immediately call onCreateView and of course cause troubles (because at that time the Service is not called and i don't have data ready for this Fragment reference!).

I also try to use event listeners and make Fragments only populate Views when parent Activity notify (when data is available) but because of the use of PagerAdapter, i can't manage when a Fragment has been created View and of course when appropriate for it to populate content!

The thing i wonder is: Is it correct that when we rotate the screen, the Activity will be destroyed and recreate? If that true, why in this situation the Activity not going to do the same thing as it was created in the first time?
So, can anybody suggest me an idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, usually you store those info in a **[Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)**:

```
void createMyFragment(value) {
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putParcelable("key", value);

  Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}

@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  value = bundle.getParcelable("key");
}
```

If you cannot do that, you may for example in your case move your call of `viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)` to `onActivityCreated()` instead of doing it in `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   viewPager = (ViewPager) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity()));
}
```